# About passing referrer php

Tags: php, html

I know that this is answered but i cajnt find the answer...
I want to pass within a `hidden field`  the value of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`
I dont know how value in `<input type='hidden' value=''/>` should be echoed ..
It is sent through post... I tried using `rawurlencode( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]))`  but i have to do decode again... Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<input type='hidden' value='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) . "' />";
```

Comment: is this safe for multibyte string and any input?

Comment: @Parhs Pass your character set as the third argument. It will escape any characters that have special meaning in HTML and therefore could be malicious. Oh and +1 to you @zerkms.